# change header position to left or below c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, textbox, header

Can I change the position of the header attribute in a TextBox object? If I wanted it to be to the left or below instead of the default - above - is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

in your situation i think you should use the anchor to define the edges 

set the **Anchor to Bottom, left**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextBox>
      <TextBox.Header>
           <TextBlock  Text="Your Header Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
      </TextBox.Header>
 </TextBox>
```

If you mean the total position related to the TextBox, I would use a `GridView` with a `Label` as Header. Something like:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0">Header:</Label>
        <TextBox
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding Path=XXX}" />
```